# removing a link from a date in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to remove the link from the "posted on date" on my wordpress site. I still want the date showing. I have managed to remove the link from the post title by adding the below to my custom CSS file.

```
.entry-title {
    pointer-events: none; 
}
```

I was hoping to use

```
.entry-meta {
    pointer-events: none; 
}
```

to achieve the same but it removes the links to categories and genres too which I don't want. I have tried various combinations using entry-date etc. but with no success. I'm using a custom theme and I can't find the relevant sections in the php files. If it's useful my site is at https://audioscapist.net.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found how to do it by using

```
.entry-header {
    pointer-events: none;
 }
```

It's only taken me all day.